# reading a file created from a cron job

Tags: php, linux, cron

I have a small program that runs and generates a new text dump every 30sec-1min via cron.

```
program > dump.txt
```

However I have another PHP web program that accesses the text dump in a read-only mode whenever someone visits the webpage. The problem is that I believe if someone accesses the website the very second the cron job is running the webpage may only read half the file because i think Linux does not lock the file when `>` is used.

I was thinking of doing:

```
echo "###START###" > dump.txt
program >> dump.txt
echo "###END###" >> dump.txt
```

Then when the PHP webpage reads the dump in memory, I could do a regex to check if the start and end flags are present and if not, then to try again until it reads the file with both flags.

Will this ensure the files integrity? If not, how can I ensure that when I read `dump.txt` it will be intact.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than create the file in the directory, why not create it somewhere else? Then after the data's been written, just move it into the webroot and overwrite the previous set.

Example:

```
sh create_some_data.sh > /home/cronuser/my_data.html
mv /home/cronuser/my_data.html /var/www/
```

Comment: If I overwrite the previous set with mv, whilst the PHP web program is reading a 500 line dump, I may only receive half the old file or some undefined behavior?? Maybe my 4th line could be a mv command so I could still check for the 2 flags in case that rare event happens.

Comment: You might receive the old file instead of the new one due to bad timing, but barring drive failure you wouldn't ever receive half the old file. As long as you have an active pointer to the old file active, the filesystem won't overwrite that data.

The mv command doesn't have anything to do with writing a part of the file. It does move the link to the file from one inode to another in the filesystem tree. When you do a read, the filesystem guarantees you get a read from the inode you asked for.

Comment: A rename (or a move, which is the same thing really) is atomic if it is on the same file system. So all that @aestrivex says applies. If ever in doubt, look at how maildir does it.

Comment: So PHP function file_get_contents()  should either read the whole file or fail, but never half the file?